# How can I trigger a Vim autocmd when entering a Netrw window?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a pair of Vim autocmd's to toggle an option on/off upon entering/leaving a Netrw browser window (via `:Explore`, `:Vexplore`, etc.). I opened one such window and ran `:echo bufname('%')`, which showed `NetrwTreeListing 1` as the name of the explorer buffer. So I tried writing my autocommands like so,

```
autocmd BufEnter NetrwTreeListing* highlight CursorLine gui=underline
autocmd BufLeave NetrwTreeListing* highlight clear CursorLine
```

but they don't trigger. I've tried replacing `NetrwTreeListing*` with `Netrw*`, and `BufEnter` with `WinEnter` but can't make it work. What am I missing here?

*Edit*: Maybe this is related. Running `:echo bufname('%')` returns `NetrwTreeListing 1` as long as Netrw is set to browse in a "tree" (`let g:netrw_liststyle=3`). Otherwise it returns the path to the current directory. Still, I'm trying to trigger my autocmd with the "tree" option set, so it seems like it should work.

*Final*: Thanks garyjohn for the excellent answer. It pairs well with another set of autocommands I came across:

```
autocmd WinLeave * setlocal nocursorline
autocmd WinEnter,BufRead * setlocal cursorline
```

Comment: are you in vim or gvim? gui is only in gvim

Comment: @FDinoff I'm in MacVim, so gvim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These seem to work:

```
au FileType netrw hi CursorLine gui=underline
au FileType netrw au BufEnter <buffer> hi CursorLine gui=underline
au FileType netrw au BufLeave <buffer> hi clear CursorLine
```

Comment: That's awesome! I didn't realize you could nest autocommands like that.